# UK visitor visa from Germany - translation of Aufenhaltstitel (residence permit)

Tags: visas, uk, german-residents

I am a non-EU citizen and I am going to apply for a British visa from Germany, where I live now. The official guidelines are clear about *supporting* documents: they should be either in English or accompanied by a certified translation. However, it is not clear to me if my residence permit card, which is called *Aufenhaltstitel* here, should be translated as well: as I understand, the card is standard for the entire EU, but all of the information is in German. What is more, in my checklist for visa application, the information about the translation requirements is provided below the page about my passport and residence permit. Could anyone clarify if I need to translate the card as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, the **Aufenthaltstitel** (Residence Title) card need not be translated, since there is a PRADO entry that gives an English translation of the different types.

Relavant may be for them the **Type of title** you have, that can be found in the Field: **Art des Titels**.

In the **Anmerkungen** (comments) field contains the legal base on which the type was issued against.

So giving the **type** of title, with the English name, may be of assistance, the comment field should not be.

Other countries use a code in the comments field, which a translater would only repeat the code given.

---

Field: **Art des Titels** (**Type of title**)

- Aufenthaltserlaubnis

  - **residence permit**
- Aufenthaltserlaubnis (Familienangehöriger)

  - **residence permit - family member**
- Niederlassungserlaubnis

  - **unlimited settlement permit**
- Niederlassungserlaubnis (Familienangehöriger)

  - **unlimited settlement permit - family member**
- Daueraufenthalt EG

  - **long-term resident - EC**
- Blaue Karte EU

  - **Blue Card EU**

[image]

---

**Sources**:

- [PRADO - Public Register of Authentic travel and identity Documents Online](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/prado-start-page.html)

  - [Aufenthaltstitel 2011](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/DEU-HO-21001/index.html)